# Assign Facebook page to app

Tags: facebook

Hi I have a Facebook app and a separate community page.  I just noticed the "create page" link in the app settings.  Is there someway to just tell facebook to use the page I already have for the app?  I dont want to lose the likes that I already have.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this dialog: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_PAGE_TAB_URL